# Chord spelling help for piano arrangement

Tags: notation, chord-theory, arranging

I'm working on an arrangement of a song and my theory knowledge is mainly as a vocalist, so I'm a bit stuck on what would be the best option for a pianist to read/play on this certain bit of music:

[image]

The transition from Db to B/Db... I'm trying to figure out if I should be spelling that chord to best reflect the key signature, or to best reflect the chord itself.

I'm leaning toward spelling it as pictured below. I know if I name the chord B it should be spelled as a B (not B Eb Gb), but with the Db key signature do the sharps make it confusing? There's already so many flats in the this key would it drive a pianist crazy, or would it make sense because of the movement of the chords? It seems silly to me to spell it as a Cb chord just to keep all the accidentals the same. Also, is it confusing having the B chord with a "Db" bass note? Obviously, there is no Db in a B chord, but taking into account the movement (or lack thereof) of the bass line I can't bring myself to write it as a C# to match the B chord scale.

I feel like these might be stupid questions, but I'm new to arranging for musicians and just need to know I'm making the most clear and sensible notation choices for a pianist to be able to sight-read-- and I know sometimes the theoretically-correct choice isn't always the easiest to understand.

Comment: There is something very wrong with your F+7/B chord. The accidentals in the right hand don't even line up with the notes! A keyboard player wouldn't have a clue what that notation is supposed to mean without doing a double (or triple) take to stop and work it out - and why there is a sharp in an F+7 chord is another unsolved mystery!

Comment: @alephzero - no mystery. F+ itself will need to include a #5, thus C#. It isn't the 7th that is augmented ! F=7 should work out as F A C# Eb. Here with a B bass. Hence F+7/B

Comment: @Tim fair enough, but the score as written leaves me guessing whether it's supposed to be A natural and C#, or C natural and E#. The accidentals seem to be a left-over from a version with B natural an D# - which would be more plausible as Cb and Eb, as in the next bars, except Eb doesn't need an accidental anyway  ... so who knows what the composer *really* meant here???

Comment: @alephzero - looking very carefully, the natural sign is lower under the stave than the #, so must apply to the lower note, I guess.

Comment: And, of course, the chord symbol helps!

Answer (score 4):

A Cb chord works better. The reader will already have his flat hat on, so seeing Cb will be no big surprise, unlike a B chord - especially marked with a Db bass note!

The key sig is Db, so moving to a VII chord *should* involve Cb rather than B. Writing it all in C# major is a non starter. However, as a vocalist, is it of paramount importance to have it in Gb, rather than a far simpler C or D, both of which most piano players would probably prefer? And it wouldn't affect the vocal range much!

If you did that, a tone key change instead of a semitone would possibly help. If not, then start in Bb, go to C ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim!

The key sig is Db (unless you know something I don't!). I have thought about arranging the song in C or D, but towards the end it modulates a half-step, so I'd still end up in Db/C# territory starting in C-- and starting in D and modulating to D#/Eb is a bit risky for my range (taking into account how high the melody goes).

The song is "Don't You Worry 'Bout a Thing" by Stevie Wonder if that is of any use. :P

Comment: @DB428 - thanks - what a schoolboy error! Corrected; now standing in the corner with a pointy hat on.

Comment: I'm considering starting the piece in C after all. The song will end pretty soon after the modulation (there's maybe 24 bars of music afterward). Would it be okay to modulate to Db? Since I'm going up a semitone-- and as I understand, generally, upward movement should be sharped-- it should technically go to C# right? But I know that is just AWFUL for any musician. Haha. Would it be wrong if I modulated to Db instead? Or should I just try to modulate a whole tone as you suggested?

You've been so helpful! Thank you! :)

Comment: For simplicity, i'd be going  C > D.

Comment: C to Db is fine.  There's no rule that an upward key shift has to be notated in sharps.  It's not about being 'easy'.  It's about what keys suit your voice best.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - fair comment. But for a lot of players, being in C, then in D *is* easier, and it will hardly make much difference to what suits voice better. And, yes, there are no rules about upward key shifts in #. There are no rules...

Comment: It can be surprising how a semitone can make the difference between a satisfactory vocal performance and a great one.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - true, I'm well aware of that with several songs I can't harmonise to because the guitarist 'has learned it in that key, so that's where it is'. Even a tone down would make it possible to reach for me, but, no! However, in maybe 90% of cases, the range of a song doesn't preclude movement of a tone for most people. Problem usually occurs when there are several singers, and the highest and/or lowest is at their limit.

Comment: Indeed, there are many possible  obstacles to an optimum performance!